# Usare la 'y' per modificare i cognomi

Tags: word-usage, etymology, name, letters

Noto una recente tendenza della stampa satirica a terminare in 'y' alcuni cognomi; per esempio, oggi leggevo *Renzy* per *Renzi* e *Alfy* per *Alfano*.

Sapreste dire quale sia l'origine di questa modificazione, e se la stessa è usata anche in altre lingue neolatine?

Comment: An **anglicism** and a **term of endearment** used sarcastically as a **diminutive**?

Comment: La modifica ortografica di *y* per *i* finale era comune in francese (anticamente si scriveva *roy* invece di *roi*, per esempio) ed è rimasta in inglese.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe we can agree that this specific use in the Italian press is an attempt to sound "English" (many think it is "cool", "modern" - Italians are known to be xenophilous after all), hence we should call it an *"anglicism"*.

Specifically it is a diminutive form of a given name (this is called a *"hypocorism"*) and is typically used as a *"term of endearment"* ("vezzeggiativo", in Italian). Of course, such diminutive terms of endearment can also be used sarcastically as *derogatory terms*, as in the examples mentioned in the question.

I ignore the origin of the suffix *"-y"* as a diminutive (a "hypocorism by reduction"), [some say it is of German origin](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3135/origin-of-the-y-or-ie-diminutive-suffix-to-denote-intimacy-tenderness-e), egreg suggested in his comment above it is of French origin. I suspect it might be common to more than one language.

Some reading (links from english.stackexchange):

> On the origin of the English diminutive suffix -y, -ie, [The Free Library](http://www.thefreelibrary.com/On+the+origin+of+the+English+diminutive+suffix+-y,+-ie-a092803251)
>
> Etimology of suffix -y, [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-y#Etymology_2)

Answer (score 5):

In questo specifico caso, Renzy puo' essere semplicemente la storpiatura di Renzie (a sua volta derivato da un'analogia fatta fra Renzi e il personaggio Fonzie). Questo l'ho trovato soprattutto nei commenti degli utenti, non tanto nei titoli della stampa.

Comment: L'analogia fra 'Renzi' e 'Fonzie' è fonetica o dipende dalle basette?

Comment: Dipende dalla giacca di pelle http://www.giornalettismo.com/archives/1360605/matteo-renzi-nuovo-blair-giovane-berlusconi-o-fonzie/  (ma credo che stiamo andando OT :D )